# Отключение расширений в режиме разработчика и Selenium Webdriver

Tags: .net, google-chrome, chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

При работе с Selenium Webdriver через .NET c Google Chrome, с недавнего времени начало появлятся окно с предупреждением:

> расширения запущенные в режиме разработчика могут приченить вред вашему компьютеру. Если вы не являетесь разработчиком, их следует отключить, чтобы обеспечить безопастность данных.

Это сообщение относится к расширению Chrome Automation Extension

Как избавиться от него?

Comment: Правильный способ - ставить расширение из [магазина](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/), но для себя (на винде) я отключаю это предупреждение [патчем](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30361260/3959875) в каждой новой версии.

Comment: причем тут установка расширения, она тут совсем не причем! Этот способ я находил в сети, но это не подходит для приложения которое будет ставиться у клиента на машине, они подобное делать не будут у себя на компе.

Comment: Силами самого расширения (или любыми другими, которые не должны привести к лишним телодвижениям пользователя) окно не убрать. [Can't be disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23056903/3851967). От апреля 14 года, но не думаю что ситуация поменялась

Comment: За пару лет работы с Selenium Webdriver это окно вылезло впервые, значит ситуация изменилась буквально пару недель назад.

Comment: [ChromeDriver - Disable developer mode extensions pop up on Selenium WebDriver automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087724/chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-on-selenium-webdriver-au) Это оно?

Comment: Да это оно, и способ отключать через `--disable-extensions`, не правильный, а вот способ с закрытием второй вкладки через 4 секунды наверное более правильный.

Comment: Выпишите сюда ответ, который сочтете удовлетворительным.